# .vbs file replace Input Box with Today's date information. Also, how to navigate to correct window if user is not on the main menu?

Tags: vbscript, ibm-midrange

I have the following:

```
 [PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
DESCRIPTION=
[PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
OPTION EXPLICIT
autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)

REM This line calls the macro subroutine
subSub1_

sub subSub1_()
Dim strMon
Dim strDay
Dim strYear
Dim strTom
Dim strLoadLtr
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "09"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "3"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "2"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "lds*"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   strMon = InputBox("Please enter the two-digit Month")
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   strDay = InputBox("Please enter the two-digit Day of the Month")
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   strYear = InputBox("Please enter the two-digit Year")
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1700"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "04"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "A"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf14]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "all"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "8"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   strTom = InputBox("Please enter tomorrows Day of the Month")
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strTom
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1000"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "lds*"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1700"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "04"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "B"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf14]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "all"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "8"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strTom
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1000"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "lds*"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1700"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "04"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "C"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf14]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "all"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "8"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strTom
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1000"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "lds*"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1700"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "04"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "D"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf14]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "all"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "8"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strTom
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1000"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "lds*"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1700"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "04"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "E"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf14]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "all"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "8"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strTom
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1000"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "lds*"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1700"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "04"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "F"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf14]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "all"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "8"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strTom
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1000"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "lds*"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1700"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "04"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "G"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf14]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "all"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "8"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strTom
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1000"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "lds*"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1700"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "04"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "H"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf14]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "all"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "8"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strTom
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1000"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "lds*"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1700"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "04"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "I"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf14]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "all"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "8"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strTom
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1000"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "lds*"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1700"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "04"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "J"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf14]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf6]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "all"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "8"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strTom
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "1000"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf16]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf12]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[down]"
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strMon
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   sutECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strDay
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[right]"
   sutECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys strYear
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
end sub
```

I like to have the user not to have input date and tomorrow's date.  Additionally, I'd like the script to start on the correct input page rather than tell the user "make sure you're at XXYZ menu before you run the script".

I've looked at DateFormat, Now, etc, but none are working.  Any suggestions or guidance would be helpful.  First time using this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not best to just use sendkeys as that will not give you a satisfactory solution, or you will also need to inspect the screen to determine where you are, and then send the keystrokes to navigate to the correct place.

You should instead try to use cl commands to navigate your menu structure if possible. Most menu systems have a command to select a specific menu. then once you have your correct starting place, you can then navigate with sendkeys.

That said, .vbs macros run in an older version of iAccess for Windows that is not supported for versions of Windows 8+. You might do better with other scripting tools. iAccess Client Solutions (the currently supported IBM i client) macros are, in my mind, a step back from the .vbs macros, but one such tool that comes to mind is Ublu, you can google it. I am not associated with, and have not used Ublu, I just know of its existence.

Answer (score 0):

to make it easier to work with macro code, assign the presentation space and operator info area objects to aliases.

```
dim ps
dim oia
set ps = autECLSession.autECLPS
set oia   = autECLSession.autECLOIA
```

use the `GetText` function to get text from the screen:

```
title = ps.GetText(1,28,27)
```

`setCursorPos` moves the cursor to a row,column location:

```
ps.setCursorPos 21,7
```

Write a VB function that use `GetText` to determine the name of the current screen.  Like "MainMenu", "WarehouseMenu", "OrderDashboard". In this case, the `ScreenName` function identifies the WRKOBJPDM and WRKMBRPDM screens.

```
Function ScreenName( ps )
   if ps.GetText(1,28,27) = "Work with Members Using PDM" Then 
      ScreenName = "WRKMBRPDM"
   elseif ps.GetText(1,27,27) = "Work with Objects Using PDM" then    
      ScreenName = "WRKOBJPDM"
   else 
      ScreenName = ""
   end if 
End Function
```

Here is a PCOMM macro which automates the navigation between the WRKMBRPDM and WRKOBJPDM screens.

```
[PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
DESCRIPTION=
[PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
OPTION EXPLICIT
autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)

subSub1_

sub subSub1_()
dim ps
dim oia
set ps = autECLSession.autECLPS
set oia   = autECLSession.autECLOIA

oia.WaitForAppAvailable

if ScreenName(ps) = "WRKMBRPDM" Then 
   msgbox "in the wrkmbrpdm screen"
   ps.setCursorPos 21,7
   oia.WaitForInputReady
   ps.SendKeys "wrkobjpdm[enter]"
   oia.WaitForInputReady

elseif ScreenName(ps) = "WRKOBJPDM" then    
   msgbox "in the wrkobjpdm screen"
   ps.setCursorPos 21,7
   oia.WaitForInputReady
   ps.SendKeys "wrkmbrpdm[enter]"
   oia.WaitForInputReady
end if 

end sub

Function ScreenName( ps )
   if ps.GetText(1,28,27) = "Work with Members Using PDM" Then 
      ScreenName = "WRKMBRPDM"
   elseif ps.GetText(1,27,27) = "Work with Objects Using PDM" then    
      ScreenName = "WRKOBJPDM"
   else 
      ScreenName = ""
   end if 
End Function
```